# Attempted import error: 'shouldUseActivityState' is not exported from 'react-native-screens'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation, yarnpkg

I'm getting this error :

C:/Users/Mobile/node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/ResourceSavingScene.js
`Attempted import error: 'shouldUseActivityState' is not exported from 'react-native-screens'.`
before i was able to do login authentication and now it says 405 error i don't know if this is related to this error or not.I'm creating project using react native expo.

Comment: do you actually have a repro where you get this error in react-native? regarding web, this error is from ts-loader if you use it, and will go away if you use babel-loader instead

Comment: @satya164 I have this error in web. how should I use babel-loader? I even don't know whether I'm using ts-loader or no

Comment: what are you using? CRA? see https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8993#issuecomment-717233195

Comment: @satya164 I've seen this issue. Isn't babel-plugin-react-native-web enough? I'm using react-app-rewired

Comment: You need to make sure to use babel-loader like in the comment.

Comment: Refer to this Github issue for more info https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9129

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Expo 40,

I can confirm that per [this comment on 'warnings printing to console for un-exported members of react-native-screens'](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/9178#issuecomment-760143668),
you can make the compile/console warning go away if you upgrade react-native-screens to newer version — ***if** you are ok with expo warning you that your react-native-screens version number is out of range* (Expo 40 wants screens version ~2.15.0, actual current version 2.17.x)

Answer (score 0):

upgraded expo to 41.0.1 and react-native-screens to 3.0.0
~~removed warning